# Get only rows that nearest lower in Y column to X column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
------------------------------------
   X       Y
------------------------------------
   10       20
   10        5
   10        9 
   50       40
   50       30
   100      70
   100     100
```

Consider  1 ,2 , 3 rows as Group A 
and 4,5 rows as Group B
and 6,7 rows as Group C

I want to get a only one row for a group  and That row should be taken depending on the 
X, Y column values.

Y column's value which is nearest lower to the x

Expected Result

```
   ------------------------------------
       X       Y
    ------------------------------------
       10        9
       50       40
       100     100
```

Comment: The question is, what should be returned, if for a group all Y > X

Comment: Then that row is skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select x, max(case when y <= x then y end) as y
from table t
group by x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE (
 X float , Y float
)

INSERT INTO @tb (X,Y) values 
 (10, 20),
 (10, 5),
 (10, 9),
 (50, 40),
 (50, 30),
 (100, 70),
 (100, 100);

 select a.* from (
  select row_number() over( partition by X order by abs(X-Y) asc ) as rn, X, Y 
  from @tb
) a where a.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Agree..posted to let author see different approaches

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE (
 X float , Y float
)

INSERT INTO @tb (X,Y) values 
 (10, 20),
 (10, 5),
 (10, 9),
 (50, 40),
 (50, 30),
 (100, 70),
 (100, 100);

; WITH CTE AS
 (
 Select t.X,t.Y,RN from (Select tt.X,tt.Y,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY tt.X ORDER BY tt.Y DESC)RN from @tb tt )t
 )
 Select DISTINCT C.X,MAX(CASE WHEN C.Y <= C.X THEN C.Y END)AS Y FROM CTE C
 GROUP BY C.X
```